# How to take values from checkboxes row by row from a table and update DB using django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get the value of some checkboxes and update database for the rows that are checked. I don’t really know how to do it since I am only starting with Django/python.

Here is my model

```
class App_Setting(models.Model):
    setting_name  = models.CharField('Setting Name', max_length=30,
                                    unique=True, blank=False,
                                    default='None')
    setting_enab  = models.BooleanField('Enabled?', default=False)
    setting_descr = models.CharField('Description', max_length=150,
                                    blank=False, default='None')
```

Because I want the user to only be able to modify the “setting_enab” via checkbox I have built my template like this

```
{% extends "mainapp/base.html" %}

{% block title %}- Available Settings{% endblock %}

{% block mainframe %}
  <h3>Available Settings</h3>

  <div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-9">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Setting Name</th>
          <th>Setting Enabled?</th>
          <th>Setting Description</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for setting in object_list %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{ setting.setting_name }}</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"  name="mycheckbox" class="checkthis" /></td>
            <td>{{ setting.setting_descr }}</td>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
{% endblock mainframe %}
```

I have read the following thread but can’t really make sense of it.

[Django check if checkbox is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29714763/django-check-if-checkbox-is-selected)

All I want to do is for each row that have the checkbox enabled (checked):

1. Send a query to DB to update that same row where I will set field “setting_enab” to “True”
2. Update “setting_descr” for the same row with some comment (string)

Can you please guide me on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Use django's `ModelForm` and `formsets`, it'll make your life easier.

Comment: Do you mean by this that I can't acheive what I want with my intended solution? Also I had a look to your suggestion, it seem a bit hard for a beginer but I will look at it again.